# How to know the device information with the crash report that was reported in Google play store?

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play-services

A few days back I uploaded my app in the play store. Today I got a crash report and the user comments to my account. 
How can we know the details of the device from which the crash came. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the crash reporting tools like Bugsense or Acra. These are freely available and easy to integrate. Please check

Bugsense https://www.bugsense.com/

Answer (score 1):

In the **Crashes & ANRs** tab on your `Google Play Developer Console` you can see the `Device` from which the report came when opening a Crash report.

You will see two tabs, `Stack Traces` and `User Messages`, in the User Messages tab you can see on which Device the crash occured.

**Edit**:
Perhaps device information is missing if the user didn't enter a `Description` in the Crash report on the device.